# Printing significant places of integers in C

Tags: c, output

I'm wondering trying to arrange my columns in the output to line up, I want to use %g to print still and it has to be comma delimited, but I'm struggling to get them to line up.

I'm currently printing all doubles as:

```
fprintf(output, "|%-9.6g, |%-15.6g, |%-30.6g\n",x,data[2*Ndprime-value1+i],data[2*Ndprime-value1+i+1]);
```

My output is looking like this:

```
|-0.0859029, |506.929        , |-505.954                      
|-0.079767, |507.13         , |-506.212                      
|-0.0736311, |507.312        , |-506.451                      
|-0.0674952, |507.474        , |-506.671                      
|-0.0613592, |507.618        , |-506.872                      
|-0.0552233, |507.742        , |-507.053                      
|-0.0490874, |507.847        , |-507.216                      
|-0.0429515, |507.933        , |-507.359                      
|-0.0368155, |508            , |-507.484                      
|-0.0306796, |507.798        , |-507.839                      
|-0.0245437, |508.077        , |-508.675                      
|-0.0184078, |509.086        , |-509.242                      
|-0.0122718, |510.077        , |-508.79                       
|-0.00613592, |510.798        , |-507.569
```

Is there a way to line up the | and to have no space between the left number and it's comma?

I know it's a very trivial question, I can't seem to find anything on it though. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the sought spacing depends on a `double`, but the spacing occurs *after* the `double` and a comma.  Suggest printing in steps and using the return value from `fprintf()` to control the next `"%*s"`.  Untested code idea follows:

`fprintf()` returns the number of `char` printed (or `EOF` on error).

```
int len;
len = fprintf(output, "|%-9.6g,", x); 
len = (len > 13) 1 : 13 + 1 - len;
len = fprintf(output, "%*s|%-15.6g,", len, "", data[2*Ndprime-value1+i]); 
len = (len > 16) 1 : 16 + 1 - len;
fprintf(output, "%*s|%-30.6g\n", len, "", data[2*Ndprime-value1+i+1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's  how i was able to keep the rows left justified, while getting the comma to appear immediately after the number.

```
 sprintf(str1, "%.6g,", othernumbers[i]);
 sprintf(str2, "%.6g,", numbers[i]);

 printf("|%-10s |%-16s |%-30.6g\n",str2,str1,-othernumbers[i]);
```

however to solve your problem of '|' not lining up you may have to consider not using %g and using %f instead.

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ discusing '.number'

> - For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point.
> - For g and G specifiers: This is the maximum number of significant digits to be printed.

so for the number -0.00613592 it will always take a minimum width of 11 to display because of the 2 zeros after the decimal. using %f would cut it down to -0.006135. with %g you will always have the possibility of overstepping your field widths.